# Geocoder.isPresent() causes NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder

I got the following error message from Google Play Developer Console.
Besides the try/catch I cannot find anything that could give a null pointer, was it the
Geocoder.isPresent() which is not available in API 8?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxxxx.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxxxxxxx.SearchActivity.updateUserLocationNameBasedOnNewCoordinates(SearchActivity.java:367)
at com.xxxxxxxx.SearchActivity.useDeviceLocation(SearchActivity.java:338)
at com.xxxxxxxx.SearchActivity.start(SearchActivity.java:495)
at com.xxxxxxxx.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:253)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
... 11 more
```

ACTIVITY:

```
    public void updateUserLocationNameBasedOnNewCoordinates() {

    String city = null;
    String country = null;

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> list;

    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocation(userLocation.getLatitude(),
                    userLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
            Address address = list.get(0);
            city = address.getLocality();
            country = address.getCountryName();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (city == null || country == null)
        locationDescription = "Map location";
    else
        locationDescription = city + " " + country;

}
```

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the documentation of [Geocoder.isPresent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent%28%29), it says: `Lack of network connectivity may still cause these methods to return null or empty lists.` So make sure you are connected.

Other important thing is that the document says that it was added in API level 9 but you have stated `android:minSdkVersion=8` in the manifest. Try to mention `android:minSdkVersion=9` or above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks Shobhit, I will adjust the minSDK and change the code to:                             if (Geocoder.isPresent()!=null & Geocoder.isPresent())

Comment: Yaa, try change the minsdk and do `if (Geocoder.isPresent()!=null && Geocoder.isPresent()) `. Take note of `&&` not `&`.

Comment: Had to make it an object first: Boolean present=Geocoder.isPresent();
  if(present!=null && present){